# Не могу получить данные из БД из-за динамического значения при условии

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Сайт на wordpress.
Для печати забронированного PDF билета я использую плагины: woocommerce и woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips. Перед печатью, в шаблоне письма, мне нужно добавить некоторые данные из таблицы БД. В плагине есть переменная `$this->order_id` - в ней содержится номер заказа.

Я попытался сделать такой запрос к БД:

```
global $wpdb;
$wt_order_ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT booking_id FROM my_table WHERE order_id = %d;", $this->order_id);
```

В итоге ничего не выводится. Но, если запрос немного отредактировать:

```
$wt_order_ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT booking_id FROM my_table WHERE order_id = 777");
```

т.е. вместо `$this->order_id` прописать уже существующий в таблице номер заказа, например 777, то запрос работает, как положено, и я получаю необходимые мне данные.

Я подумал, может быть, в момент, когда я пытаюсь обратиться к БД, то актуального номера заказа еще нет в БД. Тогда почему `$this->order_id` я могу вывести в печать с помощью `echo` или `print_r`, но не могу использовать при обращении к БД?

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему. Мне очень нужно использовать `$this->order_id`

Answer (score 1):

Не работает потому, что в `get_result` нельзя передавать `format`. Читайте внимательно документацию про `wpdb`. Для запросов к бд в которых возможно внедрение вредоносного кода необходимо использовать метод `prepare()`. Пример:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = %s", $var );
```

P.S. Ответ на коммент (пример из документации)

```
$metakey = "'крах' БД";
$metavalue = "WordPress может 'сломать' Базу Данных если не экранировать запрос.";

$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value ) VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )",
        array(
            10, 
            $metakey, 
            $metavalue
        ) 
  )
);
```

Comment: Не работает и этот вариант. `$wt_order_ids = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE order_id = %d", $this->order_id);`

Comment: @VladSiy понятное дело) потому что вы ПОДГОТОВИЛИ (prepare) запрос к выполнению обезопасили. Теперь необходимо его выполнить с помощью метода query того же wpdb. Пример кину в мой ответ!

Comment: Пробую так, кажется же должно работать: `$wt_order_ids = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}my_table WHERE order_id = %d", $this->order_id));`, но все равно не работает.

Comment: @VladSiy тогда предположу что id не того формата подставляется типо не может подставить за место %d ваше значение, попробуйте поиграться с другими

Comment: Дмитрий, я не очень понял, что вы имеете ввиду, вы говорите про %d, %s, %f? Я смотрел значения хранятся в int.

Comment: @VladSiy типо да, просто я уже иду от обратного, не понятно почему у Вас не работает запрос, надо копаться в коде уже и дампить всё что можно. $wt_order_ids = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE order_id = %d", $this->order_id); выполните это (без query) и сделайте dump $wt_order_ids и посмотрите подставил ли он переменную правильно? и как формируется запрос. Думаю проблема в $this->order_id